# How to evaluate Vector at a point by substituting Values in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a simple Mathematica code below where I first introduce a scalar function `ϕ = ϕ[x,y,z]` and then calculate the gradient of `ϕ`.  Now, I would like to evaluate the Gradient at point P by substituting in proper values for `x, y, z`.  Please assist me with last step with plugging values into `x` and `y` into gradient.  See code Below:

```
ϕ = y^2 + z^2 - 4;
varlist = {x, y, z}
Delϕ = Table[D[ϕ, varlist[[i]]], {j, 1, 1}, {i, 1, 3}]
Delϕ // MatrixForm
P = {2, 1, Sqrt (3)}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant `y^2 + z^2 - 4 x`

```
φ = y^2 + z^2 - 4 x;
varlist = {x, y, z};
g = D[φ, #] & /@ varlist
```

> {-4, 2 y, 2 z}

```
p = {2, 1, Sqrt[3]};
grad = g /. Thread[varlist -> p]
```

> {-4, 2, 2 Sqrt[3]}

Comment: Thanks! This provides the correct answer!  Do you mind explaining the how dividing by Thread[varlist -> p] got the proper results?

Comment: @PatStarks It isn't divide, it's ReplaceAll, i.e. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html

Answer (score 1):

another approach is to make your derivative a function:

```
\[Phi] = y^2 + z^2 - 4 x;
varlist = {x, y, z};
Del\[Phi][{x_, y_, z_}] = Table[D[\[Phi], varlist[[i]]], {i, 1, 3}];
```

then you can simply do this:

```
P = {2, 1, Sqrt[3]};
Del\[Phi][P]
```

> {-4, 2, 2 Sqrt[3]}